# User based document library

Tags: 2010, document-library, powershell, document

I have a request regarding document library, basically the library will store each person's record, so the security is at user level. Instead of using mysite, I am now having two choices in my head:

1. Create one document library for each user, and give access to the users individually.
2. Create only one document library, and within the library, create a folder for each user, then aplly the security accordingly for each user.

I have tried these two approaches, both of them have their own benifits.

Anyone has experienced this situation before, or any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends, if the documents are of same category or are logically same, and there are some views/or possibility of views for lets say Managers who want to see documents from all the users... Then you should keep them in single Document Library with proper permissions!

If the documents are just related to person and its kind of his personal space, and there are no merged views then keep them in separate libraries or as you said, you can even use MySite for these documents!

The main concept is what are the chances that you need to show/work on documents from multiple people at a time!

Comment: The request is user to manage their own personal documents(CV etc),  and Manager/HR can also access these documents. So the chances of working on the same docuemnt won't be too much.

Comment: I would probably go with single document library, one reason is after creating thousands of document library, it broke some CQ webpart against document library.